# how to Obfuscation Codes in Flutter Apps

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built a app using Flutter SDK version v1.9.1+hotfix.6. how to Obfuscation to the code for my flutter app for both android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [Obfuscating Dart code](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate).

Comment: I found this ,adding this extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate to the /gradle.propertie, Is doing this thing will be sufficient , Any idea how to test whether it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

that's fairly simple,

1. generate builds with obfuscate enabled. ( below example for android )

   ```
   flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info= <-- file location -- >
   ```
2. Once a crash occurs, download the stack trace file.

   ```
   flutter symbolize -i <path to stack trace file > -d <path to stack symbols file >
   ```

for more instructions, check [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate#obfuscating-your-app)